# DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Invalid JSON response

Tags: json

when i run developer tools this is the error im getting
`<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_result() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\BIS-master\Admin\API\showAllResidentCase.php:12 Stack trace: #0 {main}`

This is the code im using where i am getting an error

`<?php`

```
include_once('../../database/connection.php');
if ($connection->connect_error) 
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
} 

$query = "select resident_case_complainant,resident_avatar,resident_case_id,resident_case_status,concat(resident_last_name,', ',resident_first_name,' ',ifnull(resident_middle_name ,'')),case_name,DATE_FORMAT(resident_case_date_updated, '%M %e, %Y')  from t_resident_case inner join r_resident on resident_id = resident_case_resident_id inner join r_case on case_id =  resident_case_case_id where resident_case_active = 'Active'";
$stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($complain,$avatar,$id,$status,$name,$case,$date);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assuming the query is parsed successfully, which it looks like it isn't.

Handle errors.

```
if ($stmt = $connection->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($complain,$avatar,$id,$status,$name,$case,$date); 
} else
    die($connection->error);
```

Comment: its still not working same error -> DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - invalid JSON response

Comment: Ohh thanks its alright now i alrd figured the error in my code. Thank you so much !